basedpyright: a decorated function inside a function/method "is not accessed"
(Not relevant to the question itself, but the example uses quart-trio package, which is similar in both interface and function to flask.)
This code has no errors:
from quart_trio import QuartTrio

app = QuartTrio(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def index() -> str:
    return "ok"

app.run()

However, this code, which I assume would be identical, reports an issue:
from quart_trio import QuartTrio

def create_app() -> QuartTrio:
    app = QuartTrio(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    async def index() -> str:           # error: Function "index" is not accessed (reportUnusedFunction)
        return "ok"

    return app

app = create_app()
app.run()

The same happens inside a method:
from quart_trio import QuartTrio

class Server:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.app = QuartTrio(__name__)

        @self.app.route('/')
        async def index() -> str:       # error: Function "index" is not accessed (reportUnusedFunction)
            return "ok"

    def serve(self) -> None:
        self.app.run()

Server().serve()

Anyone has an explanation? Is there a better way to write it that does not trigger the checker? Or is this something that should be considered a bug in basedpyright, and reported as an issue?

There's nothing wrong per se, but the type checker assumes that it's an unused local function variable... the type checker is not smart enough to be aware that the method gets attached to the local app state. In this case, I would use a type: ignore comment to suppress the limitation in the checker. That said, I would use a Blueprint over this approach to creating the application, and use top level functions connected to the blueprint.

@flakes Oh, I think I get it, thanks for the nudge! I originally thought that the checker was smart enough to understand the annotation is "using" the function; but it is just that, because it is in main scope, the function might be used elsewhere, by import; changing def index to def _index makes the diagnostic appear even in main scope. (I'm using this approach not for reusability, but to encapsulate some state, since the webserver is just one task in the system, not the main component; so I'm not sure I understand how Blueprints would help me.)

"I'm using this approach not for reusability, but to encapsulate some state" The application context (g in typical Flask) would probably be a more natural fit here (potentially could use ContextVars as an alternative to that) which avoids complex bootstrapping of the routes. Blueprints avoid needing to reference the application object directly by the route definitions, allowing you to isolate the app within a single main module. Helps greatly with avoiding circular imports that usually occur without them (routes need to know about the app, app needs to know about the routes).

Also, might not be possible, but I really like FastAPI for REST apps. Route state and dependencies are a first class concept as compared to other python frameworks where they're mostly bolted on with context globals.

@flakes I want to use the webapp as a plug-and-play module for receiving a data push from a remote client, and pass it along through an async channel; I might switch it with a JSON file reader (or a protobuf TCP listener, or maybe even a serial port reader). This is why I am not going the standard way of having a top-level web app. The web interface should only have a couple of endpoints, and will fit within a single file; no import mess. FastAPI might have been better, but I don't know it as well, so I can't comment there.

What I'm saying doesn't prevent that. I define my webapps more like how you define  normal class definitions. Think of the routes as methods, and the application state as the self object. When you create an app instance, you initialize it with the static definitions of the routes and a new state. The routes invoked for that instance only access their unique application state. This way you can have multiple instances of the application running at a time without clobbering each other. A must have for parallel integration testing, and when baking the app into non-standard setups.

A workaround is to assign to a _ variable:
def create_app() -> QuartTrio:
    @app.route('/')
    async def index() -> str: ...

    _ = index  # index() is now "used".

I have posted a corresponding enhancement request here. It was closed as "not planned", due to index being treated as a name instead of the function itself:
def create_app() -> QuartTrio:
    async def _index() -> str: ...

    index = app.route('/')(_index)  # index is unused

This leads to another workaround, which is to call the decorator on a separate statement:
def create_app() -> QuartTrio:
    async def index() -> str: ...

    app.route('/')(index)

